# Android resource not found exception oncreate

Tags: android, oncreate, runtimeexception, setcontentview

So I have my app created and it works fine on my phones that I test with, but bugsnag is showing me that it is crashing for other users. Here is the bugsnag report.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp/com.myapp.activity.Menu_dashboard}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c005c
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2812)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(ActivityThread.java:-1)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1534)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6317)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0c005c
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:210)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2107)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:1120)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:424)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.myapp.activity.Menu_dashboard.onCreate(Menu_dashboard.java:205)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6757)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2704)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2812)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap19(ActivityThread.java:-1)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1534)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6317)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

So I went to my R.Java and looked for the resource it was talking about `0x7f0c005c`, it turns out this is my main xml file for `menu_dashboard` and it is crashing on this line

```
setContentView(R.layout.menu_dashboard);
```

And yes I do have it after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` and I do have it listed in my manifest, as I seen that was the error on some of the others I looked at.

There isn't anything special on the `menu_dashboard`, just a google map and a few imageviews, but it mainly seems like it is LG phones screen size
1193x720 it crashes on.

I can't seem to recreate this issue no matter which phone I try it on (even another phone just like the users). I have even went as far as creating multiple layouts with `sw300dp`, `sw330dp`, `sw480dp`, `sw600dp`, `sw720dp` thinking that maybe the screen sized mattered. So what could be causing the main xml file to crash for certain users?

Comment: show your code on `onCreate`

Comment: rebuild or clean the project again, plz.

Comment: @WhitehorseJJ I have done this several times before sending the apk file to users, it is not a rebuild or cleaning issue, but thanks.

Comment: Please check if the image files used in menu_dashboard are included in drawable folder as it might be the case it got stored in v-24 drawable folder. Check it by show in files from settings and visiting where the drawables are stored.

Answer (score -1):

There must be some error in your xml files, or may be android studio have gone mad Try following steps if your layout files do not have any issue

1. **Files** > **Invalidate Caches/Restart...**
2. **Build** > **Clean / Rebuild Project**

If above doesn't work try Restarting your Android Studio.

Comment: This is not a clean/rebuild issue, I have done this before sending out the apk file to users.

Comment: Then there must be some problem in xml, check view ids or please share your code.